# Hiding a row in the table using class

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide, tr

I have multiples of 2 rows in my table as below. I wanted to hide 2nd row pattern everywhere in my table on page load.

I tried to hide using class "a-IRR-header" but it hides both the rows since it is a common class for both the rows.

```html
<tr>
  <th colspan="4" class="a-IRR-header a-IRR-header--group" id="B139078761545827132_1">Basis</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="a-IRR-header" id="C139079212590827137"><a  data-column="139079212590827137" href="#">Sl</a></th>
  <th class="a-IRR-header" id="C139078981375827134"><a  data-column="139078981375827134" href="#">Question</a></th>
  <th class="a-IRR-header" id="C139079056068827135"><a  data-column="139079056068827135" href="#">Answer</a></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: `$('.a-IRR-header').eq(1).hide()`

Comment: After a reformat of your HTML, it shows your *rows* don't have any classes.  I suggest **adding additional classes** where you need them.

Comment: @guradio What if i have multiple rows which are repetition of the 2 rows mentioned

Comment: @GirishRRao In that case, the solution given with my answer will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr:eq(1)').hide();
});
```

All tr with 3 th and not with the class a-IRR-header--group cuz there are tr tags with 3 th with other class which i dont want to disturb:

```
$.each('tr').function({
    if($(this).find('th').not('.a-IRR-header').length == 3)
    {
        $(this).parents('tr:first').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: What if i have multiples of the 2 rows mentioned, say some 50 rows. And i want to selectively hide the row which is of 2nd row type in the question above. Also, assume class="a-IRR-headerLink" does not exist. Please answer

Comment: So you want to hide all TR which will have three TH in it?

Comment: yes himanshu. All tr with 3 th and not with the class a-IRR-header--group cuz there are tr tags with 3 th  with other class which i dont want to disturb.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using ccs `nth-child()` like:

```
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Ex:

```css
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <!--
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>$</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  -->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think you should review the syntax of your classes, too many capitalized letters (this is a personal opinion but it will help you).

I don't really understand what you're trying to do but you can use the CSS selector :

```
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
```

If you really need to hide it on load you can use something's like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "table tr:nth-child(2)").css('display', 'none');
})
```

Comment: these classes are added by Oracle apex inbuilt. I also wanted to know what if i have multiple rows which are repetition of the 2 rows mentioned.

Comment: Right i didn't know about it :) ! I edited my post it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.a-IRR-header').eq(1).hide()
});
```

```css
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4" class="a-IRR-header a-IRR-header--group" id="B139078761545827132_1">Basis</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="a-IRR-header" id="C139079212590827137"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="139079212590827137" href="#">Sl</a></th>
        <th class="a-IRR-header" id="C139078981375827134"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="139078981375827134" href="#">Question</a></th>
        <th class="a-IRR-header" id="C139079056068827135"><a class="a-IRR-headerLink" data-column="139079056068827135" href="#">Answer</a></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```